# NameError In Django View

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a model called `Finhall` and fields under it. But in my view I want to get the value of `state` field the user clicked on in order to filter other places in that same state. After trying this codes, I'm getting the below error:

```
                  global name 'finhall' is not defined
```

Models

```
class Finhall(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    state=models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Las vegas')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)
```

Views

```
def homedetail(request,finhall_id,slug):
     qs=Finhall.objects.all()

     try:
         post=qs.get(id=finhall_id,slug=slug)
     except Finhall.DoesNotExist:
         post=None

     if post:
        similar_posts=qs.filter(finhall.state) #this line is causing the error

     else:
        similar_posts=Finhall.objects.none()
     return render_to_response('homedetail.html',{'post':post,'similar_posts':similar_posts},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I've been trying to fix this error all day yet no success!

Comment: Why `finhall.state`? Shouldn't it be `post.state`?

Comment: I tried it and I'm getting the same error! :(

Comment: After restarting my server, I'm getting too many values to unpack error. Any idea?

Comment: I tried this, 'similar_posts=qs.filter(state=post.state)' is now working! Thanks for the idea!  But how can I exclude the current city in the state from the ones it will filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the line I fixed:

```
   similar_posts=qs.filter(state=post.state)
```

Thanks to Matthias for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the libraries?

```
from app.models import Finhall
```

Copy your model for more information.